# Add Object Collection to another Object Collection without iterating

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have a collection of objects objcol1(example Collection of cities in a state) and another object collection objcol2(example collection of cities in a country). Now I am querying for objcol1 and I want to add it to objcol2. I can do this by iterating through objcol1 and adding one by one to objcol2 but can I directly add objcol1 to objcol2 like 
**objcol2.add(objcol1);**

Can anyone tell me whether it is possible without iterating? If yes please explain me the process

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use the [`Enumerable.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) extension method:

```
objcol1 = objcol1.Concat(objcol2)
```

I'm sure under the covers somewhere it actually iterates, but you won't need to write the code to do it.

NOTE: This will only work if your `City` objects are the same, alternatively you could use `Select` to map the objects.

Comment: may be because you didn't use objcol1 = objcol1.Concat(objcol2);

Comment: @M.Babcock yes your answer is correct as far as I see it +1 too

Comment: And how would you do this if `objcol1` is accessed by a getter and has no setter?

Comment: @sydd - You can't with `IEnumerable` directly as it's more or less immutable. Might be better off using a `List<T>` or similar instead.

Answer (score 12):

You can also use `AddRange` of the List. See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) for more information.

```
var a = new List<string> { "1", "2" };
var b = new List<string> { "3", "4" };
a.AddRange(b);

// a would contain "1", "2", "3" and "4"
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible depending upon your use case.  If you don't care what the "collection" type is, then you can use the linq Concat command to create a new enumerable that, when iterated, will include items from both collections.

```
var collection1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var collection2 = new [] { 4, 5, 6};

var concatenated = collection1.Concat(collection2);
```

If, on the other hand, you need to actually insert the items into the existing collection, you'll need to iterate.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need a new var:

```
collection1.AddRange(collection2);
```