# Adding integer arrays to list

Tags: c#

I have a list of integer arrays:

```
List<int[]> MyList = new List<int[]>();
```

When trying to add an array to this list like this:

```
MyList.Add({ i, j });
```

The program won't compile, however this it has no issue with

```
int[] k = { i, j };
MyList.Add(k);
```

Why is the first method not valid and is there a better way than the second to carry out this task?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Object Collection to another Object Collection without iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492404/add-object-collection-to-another-object-collection-without-iterating)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{ i, j }` is short syntax for creating a new array and currently it only works at declarations. you can not use the same syntax for creating array anywhere else.

you can write

```
MyList.Add(new[]{ i, j });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this.

```
  MyList.Add(new int []{ i, j });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `MyList.Add(new int[] { i, j });`